# Can someone help me troubleshoot this addon?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I want to make it so I (and my students) can access the Graph Editor's "Key" menu from the Timeline. This is very easy to do by changing the source code: in `space_time.py` I just need to add `sub.menu("GRAPH_MT_key")` under the class `TIME_MT_editor_menus(Menu):` as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

However, I would really like to do this via an addon so that it is easier to distribute to my students. I am relatively new to addon coding, so I am probably missing something huge, but it seems like all we should need to do is append the Key menu to the Timeline editor menus. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Timeline Key Menu",
    "blender": (3, 6, 0),
    "location": "Timeline > Key",
    "description": ("Adds the graph editor's Key menu to the Timeline window"),
    "category": "Animation",
}

import bpy


def register():
    bpy.types.TIME_MT_editor_menus.append(bpy.types.GRAPH_MT_key)  

def unregister():
    bpy.types.TIME_MT_editor_menus.append(bpy.types.GRAPH_MT_key)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which menu items do you want to reach, not available from a right-click?

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.types.TIME_MT_editor_menus.append()` takes a draw function as parameter.

Below is a sample code also available in `Templates > Python > Ui Menu` in the Blender Text Editor.

```
import bpy


class CustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("wm.open_mainfile")
        layout.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile").copy = True

        layout.operator("object.shade_smooth")

        layout.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        # use an operator enum property to populate a sub-menu
        layout.operator_menu_enum("object.select_by_type",
                                  property="type",
                                  text="Select All by Type",
                                  )

        # call another menu
        layout.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Unwrap").name = "VIEW3D_MT_uv_map"


def draw_item(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu(CustomMenu.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomMenu)

    # lets add ourselves to the main header
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.append(draw_item)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomMenu)

    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(draw_item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=CustomMenu.bl_idname)
```